# How to validate Entry control on Button clicked Event and Textchanged event in xamarin.forms?

Tags: .net, validation, xamarin.forms

**How to validate Entry control in xamarin.forms ?**

**I want to validate Entry control on button Click event in xamarin.forms native application.**

Already i have tried to use **xamarin.forms behaviors**.

**How can i validate using another method ?**

[image]

**I want to make validation on each and every Entry control on text change event.**

**Want to show validation after entry control end like this....**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RegisterButton.Clicked += (sender, e) => {

  if (Validate()) {
    // complete Registration process
  }

};

private bool Validate() {

  // perform test for each field on page
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(NameField.Text)) {
    DisplayAlert("Error","Please enter a value for Name", "OK");
    return false;
  }

  // repeat for next field - some fields may have different, 
  // or multiple validations, depending on your business rules

  // if all validations pass, then return true
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I want to create validation with icon in every textbox end.....
For more details show my updated post...

Comment: @Jason we can display alert message for every invalid input on button click